# cronjob + upstart for a node.js script

Tags: linux, cron, node.js, upstart

I can start my node.js script as a process like so:

```
start demo
```

because in `/etc/init/demo.conf` i have:

```
respawn
respawn limit unlimited
exec node /home/engine/private_js/demo.js >> /home/engine/logs/demo.log 2>&1
```

But if I do `nano crontab -e` and put ether of the following ...

```
*/1 * * * * start demo
1 * * * * start demo
* * * * * start demo
*/1 * * * * node /home/engine/private_js/demo.js
1 * * * * node /home/engine/private_js/demo.js
* * * * * node /home/engine/private_js/demo.js
*/1 * * * * /usr/local/bin/node /home/engine/private_js/demo.js
1 * * * * /usr/local/bin/node /home/engine/private_js/demo.js
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/node /home/engine/private_js/demo.js
```

... then `/etc/init.d/crond restart` and wait one minute, nothing happens.

I am trying to get my node.js script to start after one minute and always check each minute even though I have the respawns (I want to be "double safe than sorry") and this method would also be good for when the server may go-down or restart for whatever reason.